# Where to store secret token for an embeddable web widget?

Tags: architecture, local-storage

I want to create a Live Chat web widget - component, that can be embedded on ecommerce website and allow business owner to talk to users/customers (like Intercom). In my architecture design, I figured out that I need to store some kind of secret/token, that identifies conversation. System should remember conversation when user returns to ecommerce after some time.

However I don't know where to put such a secret token (my web widget is loaded via iframe). Should I use localStorage? Or something else?